# Lifting function to Option

Tags: rust, functional-programming, monads, lifting

Is there a way to lift a simple function, like this

```
fn add(a:i32, b:i32) -> i32 {a+b}
```

to operate on `Option` (or any other monadic type), similar to how one would use `Applicative` in `Haskell`

I'm aware of this solution:

```
pub fn add(a: Option<i32>, b: Option<i32>) -> Option<i32> {
  Some(a? + b?)
}
```

but that requires me to actually write a separate function, that is tightly coupled with `Option`, whereas what I want is to be able to lift an arbitrary function to an arbitrary monadic type, or some other way to re-use functions operating on simple types with arguments and return values of monadic types

```
// something like this
let func = Option::lift2(add) //example, not working code
```

I'm obviously thinking `Haskell`, maybe there's more idiomatic way of doing this in `Rust`

Comment: Rust doesn't have higher ranked types, so you are unlikely to find something satisfactory that is generic over monads or applicatives. This type of thing can be a fun exercise but idiomatic Rust is _very_ different from idiomatic Haskell - there just isn't the same level of expressive abstraction available.

Answer (score 4):

You could start out with this:

```
fn lift<A, B, C>(f: impl Fn(A, B)->C) -> impl Fn(Option<A>, Option<B>)->Option<C> {
    move |oa, ob| {
        match (oa, ob) {
            (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(f(a,b)),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Or, to make it shorter:

```
fn lift<A, B, C>(f: impl Fn(A, B)->C) -> impl Fn(Option<A>, Option<B>)->Option<C> {
    move |a, b| Some(f(a?, b?))
}
```

Beware that you would possibly need similar things for `FnMut` and `FnOnce`, too.

Moreover, the above is still bound to `Option`, and not generic over monadic things in general, which is afaik quite cumbersome to simulate in Rust (if possible at all).

Comment: How come something like this isn't included into `Option` module?

Comment: @dark_ruby Probably because idiomatic Rust relies a lot less heavily on function combinators in general. These operations make a lot more sense in a world where you can define and use them in a highly abstract way.

Comment: The function body can be simplified to `move |a, b| Some(f(a?, b?))`, which is analogous to what the OP already suggested in the question.

Comment: Isn't [`Option::zip_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.zip_with) more or less that?

Comment: @rodrigo It doesn't return a new function. You could use it in the function body to define the inner closure: `move |a, b| a.zip_with(b, f)`, but in my opinion it would only obfuscate what the function is doing, and it's not more concise. Moreover, `zip_with()` is unstable.